# Groovy: Access class.value without calling getValue()

Tags: java, groovy, return-value, default, getvalue

I can't find information about this.
I wrote a DataType class and want to return the value property as the default

```
MyInteger{
  Integer value

  MyInteger(Integer iv)
  { 
     this.value = iv
  }
}
```

How can I get the value without calling getValue() ?

```
MyInteger i = new MyInteger(5)
print i.value //works
print i.getValue() //works
print i //this is what I want to achieve
Integer realInt = i //or more specific this
```

The Standard Integer is capable of that, but how?
Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Unfortunately not... The print is just an example. Maybe it gets clearer if I would say:
`Integer realInt = new MyInteger(5)`

Comment: You can implement asType so that “Integer realInt = i” works as you’d expect.

Comment: For “print i” to work you just need to implement toString.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken about asType. It is used for “i as Integer”. But the Number conversion (discussed below) is built into DefaultTypeTransformation#castToType so you can do a direct assignment to an Integer variable.

Comment: Also interesting. I’ll test it too after my vacation!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was your intent, but a "new integer" can be crafted and used like so:

```
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor()
class MyInteger extends Number {

  Integer value

  @Override
  int intValue() {
    value.intValue()
  }

  @Override
  long longValue() {
    value.longValue()
  }

  @Override
  float floatValue() {
    value.floatValue()
  }

  @Override
  double doubleValue() {
    value.doubleValue()
  }
}

def my = new MyInteger(4)

assert my.value == 4
assert my.getValue() == 4

int integer = (int)my
assert integer == 4
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks promising. I’ll test it after my vacation!